# Is there a way to get the current URL with current port number in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, url

Is there a function in Symfony 2.7 which returns the current absolute URL with the current port number?

Comment: where are you trying to get this? inside a controller action?

Comment: @Chausser Yes, and and I want to pass it in a template where I have a PayPal buynow button. The URL will be the return URL of the button

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generating an absolute url should include the port.

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
...

public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $link = $this->generateUrl(
        'route_name', [
            'route'=>'params'
        ],
        UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL
    );

    return $this->render('template', [
        'link' => $link;
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Solved, thanks. I was trying to construct the url by myself, like: `$url = "www.example".$port.$port."/someAction"`. Generating an absolute url is absolutely the right way. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

The `Request` object holds both URI and port. So from within a Controller you can

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $uri = $request->getUri();
    $port = $request->getPort();
}
```

If you're not in a Controller make sure to inject the `RequestStack` in your class an then fetch uri and port from the master-request

```
$requestStack->getMasterRequest()->getUri();
```

Comment: Let's say I'm in a controller `indexAction`. From here I want to pass in my PHP template a URL referring to anther controller, e.g. `nextAction`, included the current user port number.

Answer (score 5):

You can directly use `{{ app.request.uri }}` in your twig template.

Ex: If current URI is http://www.example.com:8080/page?q=test&p=2 then `{{ app.request.uri }}` will return the same string.